# Twilio and WhatsApp's New Feature: Carousel Template Support in WABA

Tags: templates, twilio, whatsapp, twilio-api

I'm curious if Twilio has any plans to support the creation and sending of carousel templates for WhatsApp, as outlined in Facebook's documentation: [Carousel Templates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/business-management-api/message-templates/carousel-templates).

In the meantime, is there a way to create and get approval for these templates directly through WhatsApp Business API (WABA) and then, once approved, send them via Twilio?

Thanks for any insights or guidance!

I`m would like to send a carousel using twilio.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, Carousel Templates are not supported by Twilio but we're constantly working on extending the list :)

To guarantee compatibility with other channels, such as FB Messenger and MMS, we ask our customers to create templates with out [Content Template Builer](https://www.twilio.com/docs/content/overview). The templates created there will then also be visible in the WABA.